# What is the northernmost location on the north american continent, reachable by four-wheel drive?

Tags: canada, overland, alaska, off-road

Since my original plan (Driving to Barrow, Alaska) [seems impossible](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7810/248) without turning the start of my world-trip into a major overland expedition, I'm trying to find out what the most northern location on the North American continent is, that can be reached by four-wheel drive.

I'm most likely looking for the name of a village/town/city or seasonal settlement, one that has roads/tracks leading to the place.

A likely candidate is [Prudhoe Bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prudhoe_Bay,_Alaska) close to [Deadhorse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadhorse,_Alaska), being the start of the Dalton 'Highway' (a gravel road).

However, looking at maps, online resources, atlasses etc, I get the impression that there might be other locations with a higher latitude number? But many sources fail to list really small places/roads.

Comment: So wait you gave two northernmost roads, which one is it? Just curious.

Comment: Now if it wasn't for the Darién Gap between Panama and Columbia we could drive from the Arctic in Canada or Alaska to the Antartic at the very south of Argentina.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The northern most road would be the [Dalton Highway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_Highway) which ends in [DeadHorse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadhorse,_Alaska) and extends to [Prudhoe Bay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prudhoe_Bay).

The northernmost road in Canada is [Dempster Highway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster_Highway), which ends a couple of degrees of latitude south of the Dalton in [Inuvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuvik), so that would be the northernmost you can get on existing roads.

It is also possible that you might be able to travel on [Ice Roads](http://www.history.com/shows/ice-road-truckers) which potentially could go even further north but you will have to check where they are and if you will be allowed to travel them alone but [Tours are available](http://spectacularnwt.com/what-to-do/winter-adventure/ice-roads)

Comment: Have you been there? or is this internet knowledge?

Comment: Never been. Have been planning.

Comment: A few months ago, the road from Inuvik to Tuktoyaktuk was opened, so you can now drive to the Arctic coast in Canada.

Answer (score -2):

The Dempster Highway goes up to Tuktuyuktuk now. Farther north than Prudhoe Bay.

Comment: Wikipedia has Tuktoyuktuk at 69°26' N latitude and Deadhorse at 70°12' N.  Looks like the Dalton Highway still wins.

Comment: I'd rather go to Tuktoyaktuk anyway, because I'd hate to drive so far but not be able to go to the beach. Unfortunately [the all-season road to Tuk won't open until next year](http://www.cbc.ca/beta/news/canada/north/inuvik-tuktoyaktuk-highway-1.3526669).