# How can I visit the airbase at Attu Island?

Tags: islands, alaska, military, charter

I am researching a book about Attu Island during WWII.  How would I go about getting permission to visit the old airbase there?  How would I charter a boat to the island?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Travelling to Attu Island](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/travelling-to-attu-island)

Comment: I think this one is different than the other question, as it ask specifically about the airbase, while the other one is just how to get to the island.

Comment: @pnuts: That seems to be nearly 10x too far. By great circle, [ATU-ANC is 1481 miles](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=atu-anc).

Comment: @pnuts: I wonder if they went [via Dubai](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=atu-dxb-anc). :)

Answer (score 4):

Alexai Point Army Airfield is the airfield used in World War 2. The Airfield is abandoned and can be visited without permission having closed in 1946.

Further west, he naval airfield that became "Naval Air Facility Attu" is also closed but can be used for emergencies, however I suspect that you are more interested in Alexai Point

Answer (score 0):

I was stationed at Loran A/C Station in 1970-1980 when Mr. Wayne L. Green visited the island doing research for his book  Allegiance. Also, I'm sure you must have read Thousand-Mile War by Brian Garfield. If you ever make it there you must visit Engineering Hill. I don't know the condition of the runways are in but my guess is that it would cost less to get a charter flight.

---

I was referring Attu, Alaska. You may be thinking I was talking about a a Lear jet or something like that. What I had in mind was a bush plane, if you could find one.